# Can de search key of MATCH be a row of values?

Tags: google-sheets

I am would like to use the values in the name column `(search key)` and look them up in a table with the headers `[name, regular, overtime]`.

The formula I am using is:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(rateTable, match(formName,workers,0),match(formType,rateTypes,0),0)*{formHours})
```

It works except the search key in the `MATCH` formula, does not reference every respective entry in the name column, but only works with one fixed reference to a cell.

Am I trying to use this formula beyond its capabilities? I'd like to know if I should stop searching. Thanks.

Here is a link to a copy of my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sovuTB4zSTpl0RUHciYltr-pf8g4KPTgkYVE5lB4Ifk/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ArrayFormula(index(rateTable, match(formName,workers,0),match(formType,rateTypes,0),0)*{formHours})
```

Comment: You have to change the sharing settings so Anyone With The Link Can: View. It's private at present.

Comment: Oops, I have changed the link settings. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @JoelReid Thanks for letting me know. It's fixed.

Comment: Still private. Try right-clicking your link and choosing to open it in a new private/incognito window. When that works, you'll know everyone can copy it.

Comment: @JoelReid sorry, it's working now and I have tested it. Moved it from teams to my private drive and changed the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this task is best if you use `VLOOKUP` formula. paste in **`I2`** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(formName), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(formName, rateTable, 
 IFS(formType="Regular",  2, 
     formType="Overtime", 3), 0)) * formHours, ))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sovuTB4zSTpl0RUHciYltr-pf8g4KPTgkYVE5lB4Ifk/edit#gid=768701274)**

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX` doesn't work with arrays as needed for `ARRAYFORMULA`. Either…

use copied formulas rather than a single `ARRAYFORMULA`, e.g.
`=IF(NOT(LEN(A2)),"",index(rateTable, match(C2,workers,0),match(G2,rateTypes,0))*H2)`
and drag-copy it down column I,

or refactor your `INDEX(,MATCH(` use to rely instead on `VLOOKUP`s and `HLOOKUP`s.

Comment: Thank Joel. That’s what I needed to know.